# Use SQL Server for file queue storage

Tags: sql-server, database, filesystems, storage

We are developing file processing system where several File Processing applications pick up files from queue, do processing and put back file to queue as response. Now we use Windows file system(share a folder on network) as queue. We share one folder and put files in it, the File Processing Servers applications pick up files from it and put back after processing.

We are thinking to move the whole queue engine system from windows file system to SQL Server. Is it good idea to store files into SQL Server and use SQL Server as file queue backend? The files are about 1-20mb in size and our system process about 10 000 files per day.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but I'd prefer a queue - either a remote instance or an in-memory object.  I would prefer a real queue because I could pool listeners and have the queue hand off requests to them and manage their life cycle.  You'll have to write all that code if you put them in a database.

10,000 files per day means you need to process one every 8.64 seconds for 24 hours a day.  What are your typical processing times for a 1-20MB file?

The processing of the files should be asynchronous.

If you have 50 listeners, each handling one 20MB file, your total memory footprint will be on the order of 1GB.

As far as speed goes, the worst case is the 15 minutes for processing time.  That's four per hour, 96 per day.  So you'll need at least 104 processors to get through 10,000 in a single day.  That's a lot of servers.

You're not thinking about network latency, either.  There's transfer time back and forth for each file.  It's four network hops: one from the client to the database, another from the database to the processor, and back again.  20MB could introduce a lot of latency.

I'd recommend that you look into Netty.  I'll bet it could help to handle this load.

Comment: Our file processing applications are hosted on different server machines, we can't use in-memory queue. Do you know any good/fast remote queue system? 
The file processing takes about 1-15minutes range.

Comment: You're already in bed with SQL Server - why not MS MQ?  Or ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ or OpenJMS (sorry, I'm a Java guy).

Answer (score 0):

The file size is quite nasty - unless you can e.g. significantly compress the files, the storage requirements in SQL might outweigh any benefits you perceive.

What you might consider is a hybrid solution, i.e. modelling each incoming file in SQL (fileName, timestamp, uploadedby, processedYN... etc), queuing the file record in SQL after each upload, and then use SQL to do the queueing / ordering (and you can then run audits, reports etc out of SQL)

The downside of the hybrid is that if your file system crashes, you have SQL but not your files.

Comment: The file size is not big deal, the files will be stored temporary in database as queue item and after processing will be removed. The main factor in our system is SPEED. How fast queue will receive/send files from client to File Processing app and back.